# NAS Recommendations for a specific feature set

Tags: nas

I'm looking for a NAS that meets my specific feature set and needs. My use case is a home user who needs to share file storage between multiple computers over a local network and still be able to connect to the NAS from the internet via my cable connection. I'm looking to have a security system that can support multiple users. Ideally the NAS can authentication from accounts on my "sever" conputer (a mac mini) but I would be OK with it handling security internally. All my devices are Apple, no PCs need to connect to this

For the external connection I am aware I'll have to setup port forwards and its not anything to do with the NAS it self.

General Breakdown of features - In order of importance.

1. Supports APF - That is the Apple File protocol. Other protocols welcomed but not needed.
2. Mutli-User support - I'm looking to have at a minimum 3 users, they should not have access to each others files
3. Support 1TB to 6TB of usable storage.
4. Raid support
5. Be able to grow the storage size over time without loosing data
6. Gigabit wired connection. Other connection types welcomed (usb/firewire/wirless/etc.) but wont be used.

Thats it. I am *not* looking to have this do anything other than be a NAS... no bit-torrent downloads, not a web server (though web configuration is fine), not a media (TV) center, etc. Also, I am *not* looking to build my own, I've done the build your own PC in the past and they work great but I don't have the time or the desire to go that route. I'm looking to plug it in, turn it on, and forget about it type of device.

I'm looking to spend $200.00 to $1,000.00 USD on the product. If the product is over a grand but you think it would be an ideal match, I would still be interested in hearing about it. I am aware of the Time Capsule products that apple offers. I currently own one and am not happy with the product.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Drobo](http://www.drobo.com/)

Comment: This misses #2 from my list. I'm hoping to find one that includes them all. Not a bad thing, but the Drobo has a bunch of extra features that I'm not looking for.